# Create custom oAuth Server With Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, oauth

is it possible to create a custom oAuth server with the Zend Framework Zend_Oauth? For example i want to create a REST service and have oAuth authentication? Does the zend framework have support for this out of the box?>

Comment: Maybe this is duplicated with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061435/zend-framework-oauth-provider

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no working OAuth server/auth adapter.  There are a few of us (including myself) working to meld the existing Zend_Oauth into a Zend_Auth_Adapter.

Find me on twitter @onyxraven and we can discuss.  I should have an idea of what needs done before the end of the week.

Comment: I second the comment above, if you have a working solutions will be great if you share here

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at http://oauth.net/code/ ?

There is a community contribution:

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/incubator/library/Zend/Oauth/Server.php