# Zend Framework Oauth Provider

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, oauth-provider

How can I add a Oauth provider to a web application using Zend Framework? Zend Framework has support for oauth consumers, but I don't see a provider support. What do you use to implement a Oauth provider in php (with Zend Framework)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I followed [this guide from Rasmus Lerdorf](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/55-Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-Service.html) to implement an OAuth provider.

While I didn't actually use the pecl extension, you can use the article to write your own server component.

Comment: Have you thought about submitting it to their incubator program. I see no signs of updates to the Zend_Oauth_Server I linked to in my answer, so maybe they stopped working on it. It would be nice to have even a semi-operable server component for Zend to experiment with though, so if you have it in a github repository or the like, please post.

Comment: I would like to, but it was produced for my employer and as such isn't mine to give away. It is actually quite a simple component, just a couple of controller base classes with methods you need to implement for persisting/validating parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the zend incubator, it has a new `Zend_Oauth_Server` file

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/incubator/library/Zend/Oauth/

I think Brandon's correct in saying that a Provider doesn't exist yet in Zend, but I think this class maybe a future provider they're working on.

We're looking at implementing a provider for one of out projects at work, so I'll probably have to research this in depth soon. Keep me posted if you find more info on this yourself and I'll keep this thread updated on my side.