# Make my own api with oauth

Tags: php, api, oauth

Hy ,

I want to make my own api (api.mysite.com).
   But i want to secure it with OAuth.
   I couldn`t find a good tutorial on how to implement it.

I would like something like this:

On api.mysite.com to be the files for oauth :

-where user sends the signed request and i return him the needed data (first send him something like 1 or 0).

And on localhost/testapi to be the file index.php:
  -where user signs the request and sends it to api.mysite.com where it is processed and returns the result if it`s all ok

Where could i find the best tutorial that explains what to put on api.mysite.com , what to put in localhost/testapi and the sql structure?

Thank you and sorry for my dumbness

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061435/zend-framework-oauth-provider which gives this article as an answer: http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/55-Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-Service.html

Comment: No , it is not a duplicate. I don`t want anything to do with zend framework or other stuff like that

Comment: checkout the link in the answer, it's not related to the zend framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some useful links:

- [standard-compliant implementation of oauth2 provider in php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/)
- [a tutorial](http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5/)
- also, search stackoverflow, there were questions like yours before

Comment: Thank you, i will come back with a review.